# Having trouble extracting parsed url in files for more scraping and parsing

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests

**Problem Introduction** Language: Python 3.8

Operating System: Windows 10

Any other relevant software: Jupyter notebook and html-requests

*Problem Statement*
I have a folder of excel files that contain scraped webpages. My goal is to learn more about scraping and parsing by extracting the url from the file and parse through it more to get more information.

```
test_database=pd.read_csv('questionsonpage27.csv')
test_database.shape
len(test_database)
```

Isolate the urls:

```
test_database.iloc[:,4]
```

returns a url

Things I have tried:
FIRST ATTEMPT: initially I used '.iloc[0,4]' instead and it returned almost the right number of files with almost the right content (baby steps). I recognize this only uses the url for the first row as the content for every file but...

```
number=len(test_database)
    
for i in range (1,number):
    url = test_database.iloc[0,4]
    r = requests_html.HTMLSession().get(url)
    with open (f"questionparse{i}.csv", 'w') as f:
            data = []
            for tag in r.html.find('.container'):
                data.append(
                    dict(
                        post = tag.find('.post-layout', first=True).text, 
                       # votes    = tag.find('.vote strong',        first=True).text, 
                        #tags     = tag.find('.tags',               first=True).text, 
                        #summary  = tag.find('.excerpt',            first=True).text, 
                        #url      = tag.find('.question-hyperlink', first=True).absolute_links.pop()
                    )
                )
                df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
                df.to_csv(f"questionparse{i}.csv", index=False)
            #page+=1
            time.sleep(1.3)
```

using the correct .iloc[:,4] yielded an error, so I hunted around more and came up with SECOND ATTEMPT which I think is closer but I dont even get a result:

```
for i in test_database:
    url = f"test_database.iloc[{i},4]"
    r = requests_html.HTMLSession().get(url)
    with open (f"questionparse{i}.csv", 'w') as f:
            data = []
            for tag in r.html.find('.container'):
                data.append(
                    dict(
                        post = tag.find('.post-layout', first=True).text, 
                       # votes    = tag.find('.vote strong',        first=True).text, 
                        #tags     = tag.find('.tags',               first=True).text, 
                        #summary  = tag.find('.excerpt',            first=True).text, 
                        #url      = tag.find('.question-hyperlink', first=True).absolute_links.pop()
                    )
                )
                df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
                df.to_csv(f"questionparse{i}.csv", index=False)
            #page+=1
            time.sleep(1.3)
```

Intended outcome is to isolate the urls in that column and sort through them more.

Actual outcome:error message is extensive but focuses around

```
InvalidURL                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-560a6ce41e98> in <module>
      9 for i in test_database:
     10     url = f"test_database.iloc[{i},4]"
---> 11     r = requests_html.HTMLSession().get(url)
     12     with open (f"questionparse{i}.csv", 'w') as f:
     13             data = []
```

I have also tried

url = test_database.iloc[f"{i}",4]
But that didn't even pass to r=requests_html....
I have also tried test_database.iloc[i,4] but that did not work either. Any recomendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that test_database.iloc[i,4] was the correct format, I am not sure why it failed the first time.